Unable to get a valid response from Instagram Basic Display API
I'm using the Instagram Basic Display API and since a few days I'm getting the "Unsupported request - method type" error.
My APP is Live, and validated from Meta since several years.
I tried with my production code, and with a RAW cURL API calls with Postman using a valid token, and I get the same error on both.
This is an example of code I'm using getting a Long Lived User Access Token:
$params = [
      'endpoint_url' => 'https://graph.instagram.com/access_token',
      'type' => 'GET',
      'url_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'ig_exchange_token',
        'client_secret' => $this->_appSecret,
        'access_token' => $this->_userAccessToken
      ]
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    $endpoint = $params['endpoint_url'];

    if ('POST' == $params['type']) { // post
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params['url_params']));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    } elseif ('GET' == $params['type'] && !$params['url_params']['paging']) { // get
      $params['url_params']['access_token'] = $this->_userAccessToken;

      // add params to endpoint
      $endpoint .= '?' . http_build_query($params['url_params']);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $responseArray = json_decode($response, true);

    if (isset($responseArray['error_type'])) {
      var_dump($responseArray);
      die();
    } else {
      return $responseArray;
    }

And this simple call I tryed too:
    curl -X GET https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username&access_token={VALID_TOKEN}

Error:
    {
        "error": {
            "message": "Unsupported request - method type: get",
            "type": "IGApiException",
            "code": 100,
            "fbtrace_id": "A32uEK5vFtH166PBEaDxkAO"
        }
    }


What happens when you include an API version, before /me/? https://graph.instagram.com/v20.0/me

How is this problem different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78748992/im-getting-unsupported-request-method-type?

If i include /v20.0/ I get the same error. I noticed if I put my instagram account as "testing account" it works, but it has no sense since my app is validated from meta and it's in Live mode
